# Beyond vine copulas

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, independence, copula

I know that vine copulas allow for different dependency models between pairs of variables. I wondered if they are also used to model dependency models between subsets (beyond pairs) of variables or if there are any copulas or other statistical tools to model this.

Comment: Hierarchical copula models would qualify for this. This paper "[Copula based hierarchical risk aggregation through sample reordering](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.insmatheco.2012.03.009)" by PhilippArbenz, ChristophHummel, GeorgMainika explains the ideas and also includes sampling algorithms.

Comment: @gg: thanks for sharing this, I will check it out.